# Reference class from @staticmethod

Tags: python, class, methods

↑↑↑ It does NOT

Let's say I have a class with some utility methods:

```
class Utils:
    @staticmethod
    def do_stuff():
        # some stuff
        Utils.do_other_stuff()
        # some more stuff

    @staticmethod
    def do_other_stuff():
        # somehting other
```

I don't really like the `Utils.do_other_stuff()` part.

If it was instance method, I would reference it via `self`, but here I have to write the full class name.

Is this where `@classmethod` is a good idea to use, or is it overkill? - or is there some cleaner way to write Utils, perhaps with a module?

Comment: why not to convert `def Utils:` to `class Utils(object):`? so you'll be able to use `self`, if you don't want then you can just write methods in some file(module) and import it.

Comment: Why is this even a class? Why not just put all these methods in a `utils` module?

Comment: It was meant to be class, I just wrote it wrong.

Comment: @user2357112 and then use `import utils` and call it `utils.do_stuff()`?

Comment: @MightyPork: Exactly.

Comment: @user2357112 okay that's the true solution for me then, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like `Utils` will ever be subclassed or instantiated; it's just a wrapper for static methods. In that case, these methods can all be turned into module-level functions, perhaps in a separate `utils` module:

```
# No class!
def do_stuff():
    ...
    do_other_stuff()
    ...

def do_other_stuff():
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`@classmethod` is the way to go:

```
class Utils:
    @classmethod
    def do_stuff(cls):
        # some stuff
        cls.do_other_stuff()
        # some more stuff

    @classmethod
    def do_other_stuff(cls):
        # somehting other
```

Just a clarification related to *Martijn Pieters* comment: I usually avoid `@staticmethod` and I prefer to adopt always `@classmethod` because it allows me to refer to the class and its methods. (I don't agree with suggestions about writing modules with functions… I'm an OOP supporter :P)

Comment: Why is `do_other_stuff()` a class method? If you do make it a class method, do give it a `cls` first argument.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a reference to the current class (which could be a subclass), then definitely make it a `classmethod`.

That's not overkill; the amount of work Python does to bind a class method is no different from a static method, or a regular method for that matter.

However, don't use classes here unless you have to. Python is not Java, you do not *have* to use a class and functions can live outside of classes just fine.